# How to invoke migration in rake task in Rails5

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rake-task

In Rails 5, I am no longer able to use a rake task that migrates files in a different directory.  I get the error `ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError: No migration with version number 20180209214145`.

Any idea how I could do this in Rails 5?  I think that the line `ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths = ['db/manual_migrate']` no longer works as expected, but I am not quite sure how to fix it.

```
  desc 'Run db:migrate:up on a task we wish to migrate manually (e.g. not on all servers).' \
    'VERSION is required.'
  task manual_migrate: [:environment, :load_config] do
    raise 'VERSION of migration is required for this task!' unless ENV['VERSION']
    default_paths = ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths = ['db/manual_migrate']
    begin
      Rake::Task['db:migrate:up'].invoke
    ensure
      ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths = default_paths
    end
  end
```